# Gerar XML do banco de dados php mysql após consulta

Tags: php, mysql

Como gerar um arquivo xml de um banco de dados após uma consulta e em sequência fazer o download automaticamente?

Comment: é o xml do banco com todas as tabelas e campos? tem algum modelo de como seria a saida?

Comment: @rray não tenho nenhum exemplo prático de como seria, desculpe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, para responder a tua pergunta bem abrangente e com pouquíssimos detalhes, existe uma classe do PHP chamada SimpleXML que você consegue gerar praticamente tudo que voce quiser em XML a partir de quakquer tipo de dado...

Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.simplexml.php) para a referencia da classe. E para algo mais específico eu achei essa função [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php) que a partir de uma string, carrega um arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Ruggi!

Comment: @theflash se respondeu sua questão, marca ela como respondida... Obrigado!